# Using socket.io in node.js with express to display connection message when user logs in

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, express, socket.io

I am trying to write a web chat client in socket.io, but first I need to get my server talking to the website on localhost.

I am getting the 'listening' message, but nothing happens when I open up localhost in a new tab to say that a user connected. Apache server is running, so is express, so is node.js.

Here is my index.js, which serves up my index.html:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('a user connected');});

http.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('listening on *:3000');});
```

and here is my index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC>
<html>
  <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
<title>Web chat practice</title>
<style>
      * { margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }
      body { font: 13px Helvetica, Arial; }
      form { background: #000; padding: 3px; position: fixed; bottom: 0; width: 100%; }
      form input { border: 0; padding: 10px; width: 90%; margin-right: .5%; }
      form button { width: 9%; background: rgb(130, 224, 255); border: none; padding: 10px; }
      #messages { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
      #messages li { padding: 5px 10px; }
      #messages li:nth-child(odd) { background: #eee; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
Here will be the web chat:
<ul id="messages"></ul>
    <form action="">
      <input id="m" autocomplete="off" /><button>Send</button>
   </form>
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io.();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I could also use some general direction in the MEAN stack.

Comment: `var socket = io.();` is a syntax error.  And you have no client code that actually does anything with socket.io and your server code doesn't look correct either.  I'd suggest you start with a working sample app using Express and socket.io documented here: http://socket.io/docs/.  Copy a working example, see that it works as copied from the working example, then extend it to meet your needs on step at a time, testing each time you modify.  It's much easier that way to see where you went wrong than starting from scratch and wondering why it all doesn't work.

Comment: Also, get very familiar with the error logs in both nodejs and your preferred browser so you can see whenever there is an error being logged or thrown.

Answer (score 1):

This line of code in index.html creates an error:

```
var socket = io.();
```

The code should be:

```
var socket = io();
```

This will connect to your Express server/socket.io (if the web page is being served by that Express server).   That should generate the `'a user connected'` message in your server console, but it won't do anything else because your web page doesn't do anything else with socket.io.

---

In addition, your server code looks suspect.  I'd suggest you take the Express 4 example right from here: http://socket.io/docs/#using-with-the-express-framework.

I do not understand why you mention an Apache server as that is not typically part of an Express/socket.io implementation.